# Kubernetes - access service in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and trying to understand how the Spring Boot services deployed behind Cluster-IP can be accessed through the user interface service.

1. Inside frontend application we are calling backend application URL via a config.js file
2. Both applications are hosted on same nodes but different pods
3. When in frontend app's config.js file, we are mentioning clusterIP, service-name:port, of the backend app it is not accepting, it is only accepting backend nodeport service's externalIP:nodeport.
4. We also tried to access the service name with the help of different namespace for frontend application and backend service.

How to use the service name instead the IP address?

Also, is there any additional configuration required for AWS EKS?

Thanks,

Avinash

Comment: tried `servicename.namespace:port`?

Comment: Are the pods in different Namespaces? Why are you using "NodePort" for you backend service? You mean you have Two backend services? BTW, did you check whether the Service has correct Endpoints?